# Troubleshooting MQTT TLS in C# over Mosquitto

Tags: c#, ssl, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to build a local development environment with mosquitto and an MQTT client in C#.
In the first stage with no TLS, the client was working.

I build a Makefile to generate client, server and ca certificates

```
PRIVATE_KEY:= key.key
CERTIFICATE:= certificate.crt
REQUEST:= request.csr

ORGANIZATION_NAME:=a-company.com

# ca specific
CA:= ca
CA_PRIVATE_KEY := $(CA)/$(PRIVATE_KEY)
CA_CERTIFICATE := $(CA)/$(CERTIFICATE)
CA_SUBJECT:=/C=SE/ST=Stockholm/L=Stockholm/O=$(ORGANIZATION_NAME)/OU=CA/CN=$(ORGANIZATION_NAME)

generate_ca_folder:
    rm -rf $(CA)
    mkdir $(CA)

ca: generate_ca_folder
## generate the root ca private key
    openssl genrsa -out $(CA_PRIVATE_KEY) 4096
## generate the root ca certificate
    openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key $(CA_PRIVATE_KEY) -sha256 -days 1024 -out $(CA_CERTIFICATE) -subj "$(CA_SUBJECT)"

# server specific
SERVER:= server
SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY := $(SERVER)/$(PRIVATE_KEY)
SERVER_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_REQUEST := $(SERVER)/$(REQUEST)
SERVER_CERTIFICATE := $(SERVER)/server.$(CERTIFICATE)
SERVER_SUBJECT:=/C=SE/ST=Stockholm/L=Stockholm/O=$(ORGANIZATION_NAME)/OU=Server/CN=0.0.0.0

generate_server_folder:
    rm -rf $(SERVER)
    mkdir $(SERVER)

server: generate_server_folder
## generate the server private key
    openssl genrsa -out $(SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY) 4096
## generate the certificate signing request
    openssl req -new -key $(SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY) -out $(SERVER_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_REQUEST) -subj "$(SERVER_SUBJECT)"
## generate and sign the server certificate using the root ca certificate
    openssl x509 -req -in $(SERVER_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_REQUEST) -CA $(CA_CERTIFICATE) -CAkey $(CA_PRIVATE_KEY) -CAcreateserial -out $(SERVER_CERTIFICATE) -days 500 -sha256

# client specific
CLIENT:= client
CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY := $(CLIENT)/$(PRIVATE_KEY)
CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_REQUEST := $(CLIENT)/$(REQUEST)
CLIENT_CERTIFICATE := $(CLIENT)/$(CERTIFICATE)
CLIENT_PFX := $(CLIENT)/client.pfx
CLIENT_SUBJECT:=/C=SE/ST=Stockholm/L=Stockholm/O=$(ORGANIZATION_NAME)/OU=Client/CN=127.0.0.1

generate_client_folder:
    rm -rf $(CLIENT)
    mkdir $(CLIENT)

client: generate_client_folder
# generate the client private key
    openssl genrsa -out $(CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY) 4096
# generate the certificate signing request
    openssl req -new -key $(CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY) -out $(CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_REQUEST) -subj "$(CLIENT_SUBJECT)"
# generate and sign the client certificate using the root ca certificate
    openssl x509 -req -CA $(CA_CERTIFICATE) -CAkey $(CA_PRIVATE_KEY) -CAcreateserial -in $(CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_REQUEST) -out $(CLIENT_CERTIFICATE) $(Q_STDERR)
    openssl pkcs12 -export -out $(CLIENT_PFX) -inkey $(CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY) -in $(CLIENT_CERTIFICATE) -passout pass:
    
# verify that both the server and client certificates are signed by the same ca
verify_certificates: clean ca server client
    openssl verify -CAfile $(CA_CERTIFICATE) $(CLIENT_CERTIFICATE)
    openssl verify -CAfile $(CA_CERTIFICATE) $(SERVER_CERTIFICATE)
    openssl verify -CAfile $(CA_CERTIFICATE) $(CLIENT_PFX)

clean:
    rm -rf $(CLIENT) $(SERVER) $(CA)

mosquitto:
    sudo chmod 777 server/key.key
    sudo mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf

sub:
    mosquitto_sub -d -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8883 -t kostas --cafile ca/certificate.crt --key client/key.key --cert client/certificate.crt

pub:
    mosquitto_pub -d -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8883 -t kostas -m "hi" --cafile ca/certificate.crt --key client/key.key --cert client/certificate.crt

debug:
    openssl s_client -connect 0.0.0.0:8883 -CAfile ca/certificate.crt --key client/key.key --cert client/certificate.crt -state -debug

deploy:
    sudo rm /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/certificate.crt
    sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
    sudo cp ca/certificate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
    sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Apart from the generating commands( everything above **verify_certificates**), **sub and pub are testing commands from mosquitto**, **mosquitto runs the broker with the config file provided**, debug is using the **openssl debug command** and deploy **pushes the new ca to the certificate store**.

So far so good.

When I am running the broker and trying to **pub and sub**, everything works fine.

When I am trying to run it through the C# client, I am receiving the following message:

```
1698392659: New connection from 127.0.0.1:49700 on port 8883.
1698392665: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
```

Below you can see the C# sample client code
**Program.cs**:

```
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using ConsoleApp1;
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient;
using MQTTnet.Formatter;

var provider = new CertificateProvider();

var options = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
    .WithClientOptions(new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
        .WithProtocolVersion(MqttProtocolVersion.V500)
        .WithClientId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        .WithTcpServer("0.0.0.0", 8883)
        .WithTlsOptions(opts =>
        {
            opts.UseTls();
            opts.WithClientCertificates(provider.GetCertificates());
            opts.WithSslProtocols(SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13);
            opts.WithCertificateValidationHandler(provider.ValidateCertificates);
            opts.Build();
        })
        .WithCleanStart().Build()).Build();

var client = new MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient();

await client.StartAsync(options);

await client.EnqueueAsync(new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder().WithTopic("kostas")
    .WithPayload("hi").Build());

await Task.Delay(5);

Console.WriteLine(client.IsConnected);
```

**CertificateProvider.cs**:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1;

#region

using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using MQTTnet.Client;

#endregion

internal sealed class CertificateProvider
{
    private readonly X509Certificate2 _clientCertificate;
    private readonly X509Certificate2Collection _signingCertificates;

    public CertificateProvider()
    {
        _signingCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection
        {
            new("../../../../../ca/certificate.crt")
        };

        var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile("../../../../../client/certificate.crt", "../../../../../client/key.key");

        _clientCertificate =
            new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));
        _signingCertificates.Add(_clientCertificate);
    }

    public IEnumerable<X509Certificate2> GetCertificates()
    {
        return _signingCertificates;
    }

    public bool ValidateCertificates(MqttClientCertificateValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        var chain = new X509Chain();

        chain.ChainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy
        {
            DisableCertificateDownloads = true,
            RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EndCertificateOnly,
            RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck,
            TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust,
            UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0),
            VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag,
            VerificationTime = DateTime.Now,
            VerificationTimeIgnored = false,
            CustomTrustStore = { _signingCertificates.ToList()[0] }
        };

        chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.AddRange(_signingCertificates);

        return chain.Build(new X509Certificate2(_clientCertificate));
    }
}
```

**mosquitto.conf**

```
per_listener_settings true

listener 8883
allow_anonymous true
require_certificate true

cafile ca/certificate.crt
certfile server/server.certificate.crt
keyfile server/key.key
tls_version tlsv1.3
```

[I have tried all the code snippets from MQTTnet](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/wiki/Client) but unfortunately they all led to the same error code you saw above.

There is an interesting output from the **debug** command from the Makefile though, it results to the same error code as the C# code!

My questions are the following ones:

1. **How can the authentication succeed with the test clients and fail with openssl and the C# code?**
2. Does anyone have an idea of what the problem would be? I tried with the **certificate provider from the sample code as well as directly loading the .pfx file on the client** but they result to the **same error**. The verify command returns **ok for all the certificates validated by the ca**
   To me, the only logical explanation is that I have an issue with TLS and the broker configuration, but I am not sure what, not an expert on that field.
3. Is there a better way to generate certificates that **would work out of the box**?

Let me know if you need more info about the problem or further explanations!

I ran the test clients and everything was fine but when I ran the C# client and the debug command, I got the error message described above.

Comment: I assume the `openssl s_client` is failing because it's not actually sending any MQTT packets after the TLS handshake.